# Is there a way to make individual tiles of a Tilemap accessible and navigable with Voiceover in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, accessibility, voiceover, gamekit

I am a blind programmer, new to blindness but not to coding, and was wondering if anyone else has attempted this:

I am trying to make a tile based movement system for a game and want to make each tile selectable using Voiceover.  I have only seen 1 other app do this and am not sure whether he used SpriteKit or not.

I saw a few hacky ways around it such as creating a matrix of buttons on top of the tiles for VoiceOver users, but was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this including links to resources that tackle issues like these.

I am trying to implement the game with both GameKit and SpriteKit using a tile map.

Comment: I hope you're looking for keyboard navigation. If yes, are these tiles laid out vertically, horizontally or in a grid.

Comment: I been investigating tile maps over the past few weeks. The whole point of them is to simplify layout, so adding individual actions to tiles isn't going to work. Maybe you can do something with TileGroups, but I think it would defeat the object.  Tell me more I would like to help on this project?